# perl outlook from field not changing to what is written?

Tags: perl

I am putting a script together to send a test email, i need to change the from field, but this does not change to what i put on the script? also how do i request a delivery receipt from all the recipients. many thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';
use Mail::Outlook;
my $Outlook;
eval { $Outlook = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application') };
die "Outlook not installed" if $@;
unless ( defined $Outlook ) {
    $Outlook = Win32::OLE->new( 'Outlook.Application', sub { $_[0]->Quit; } )
        or die "Oops, cannot start Outlook";
}
my $outlook = new Mail::Outlook();
# create a message for sending
my $message = $outlook->create();
$message->From('#######.com');
$message->To('#####.com; ppppp.co.uk');
$message->Cc('o#####.com');
$message->Bcc('');
$message->Subject('Test');
$message->Body('Test Regards');

$message->display;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3360439 : Rather than putting the values in the From('#####.com') directly use a hash variable and send them.

```
 # Or use a hash
  my %hash = (
    From    => 'hi@live.com',
    To      => 'hello@live.com',
    Subject => 'greetings',
     Body    => 'Hello',
  );

  my $message = $outlook->create(%hash);
  $message->display(%hash);
  $message->send(%hash);
```